# Website redirects endlessly until the max-redirection is reached in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, crawlera

site behaves noramlly when accessed through browser but the redirection issue occurs while accessing the site through scrapy bots.
I use Scrapy-Crawlera proxy services, still site redirects endlessly.
If i use `handle_httpstatus_list = [302]` or `dont_redirect = True`, i will get the response as

> Object moved here.

I am hoping for any suggestions or answers as to why this behaviour occurs on certain sites? Unfortunatly i can not share the website URL.

Comment: Providing a code example might be helpful. I assume you are already using an appropriate user agent?

Comment: unfortunatly i can not provide the code example and yes the proxy service will handle the user agent appropriatly

Comment: Why? It can be an antibot measure, the time a bot is crawling endless fictional redirects is time it is not extracting actual data, and it may discourage unexperienced developers. It can also be a server-side error (when the same happens in a web browser).

Comment: It does not happen in a web browser, its when running the url through scrapy, but sometimes randomnly a successfull request will happen, but around 90% of the time, it redirects and the script stops running as the max-redirection is reached.